# Merging list of tuples in python

Tags: python

I need to merge two lists of tuples with expected result is some kind of intersection between two lists, I already have the *DUMB* solution.
List 1 has incomplete value in the last element of tuple.
List 2 has tuples that list 1 doesn't have and have tuples with complete value 
Result...hmmm
well, best described in example:

```
l1 = [('4',), ('6',)]
l2 = [('3', '1'), ('4', '23'), ('6', '34')]

#my dumb solution
def mymerge(l1,l2):
    l3 = []
    for x in l2:
        if x[0] in [ y[0] for y in l1 ]:
            l3.append(x)
    return l3

result = mymerge(l1,l2)
#result is what expected-> [('4','23'),('6','34')]
```

My question:
What other solution beside my dumb solution ? 
really curious...
Tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`list comprehension`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) should work:

```
result = [ l for l in l2 if (l[0],) in l1]
```

Similarly, you can use the inbuilt [`filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175736/tuples-partial-match) function

```
result = filter(lambda x: (x[0],) in l1, l2)
```

Comment: results in an empty list

Comment: My edit fixed the issue (needed to use tuple comparison)

Answer (score 2):

Using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) with `l2` as a dictionary is better, because

1. we don't have to generate intermediate tuples/lists
2. We will be able to do the lookup in a constant time, as we are using `dict`.

---

```
l2 = dict(l2)
from itertools import chain
print [(item, l2.get(item)) for item in chain.from_iterable(l1)]
# [('4', '23'), ('6', '34')]
```

Answer (score 1):

set lookup must be faster:

```
>>> [ y for y in l2 if y[0] in set(*zip(*l1))]
[('4', '23'), ('6', '34')] 
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [47]: l1 = [('4',), ('6',)]

In [48]: l2 = [('3', '1'), ('4', '23'), ('6', '34')]

In [49]: la = [l[0] for l in l1]

In [50]: la
Out[50]: ['4', '6']

In [51]: [l for l in l2 if l[0] in la]
Out[51]: [('4', '23'), ('6', '34')]
```